# Are nested evals allowed?

Tags: javascript, html, web, eval

I am trying to use `eval`s to run user-defined code in my HTML5/JS/CSS3 project. If the user-defined code contains an `eval`, I get the following error in the JS console when the code runs:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

at

```
eval(a);
```

with the parentheses underlined. Any tips?

BTW: I'm using Chrome

Comment: Works for me. Most likely you are having an escaping issue. Since the string inside the inner eval gets parsed twice, it has to be escaped twice. `var a = "eval(\"alert(\\\"Foobar\\\")\")";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is caused when there are ' and " in one string when a string argument is inside eval which is a string argument inside another eval. the solution is to declare a function to addshalshes just like the one on php.

when you try for example

```
console.log("hey you !");
```

it works fine, when you add eval

```
eval('console.log("hey you!");');
```

this one also works fine but if you want to wrap this code inside an eval you should add slashes like this

```
eval('eval(\'console.log("hey you!");\');');
```

which means that you always have to add slashes when the user inputs his code, this code may help you

```
str = str.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```